# How do I add two long strings containing binary digits in Java?

Tags: java

I've been trying to add two long strings of binaries using the Integer.parseInt method as radix 2. However, I don't believe that this works for long strings of binary numbers. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: By "binaries" do you mean you have `byte[]`s that represent the numbers you want to add?

Comment: An example of what I have is "10000011100" and "00000011000" but considerably longer and of the same number of characters.

Comment: Maximum you can have for `Integer.parseInt` with radix 2 is the binary of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Exactly how long is "long"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BigInteger` with radix:

`BigInteger decInt = new BigInteger("111111111111111111111111111111111001111",2);`

Have a look at the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

You can use BigInteger for this. The [`BigInteger(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-byte:A-) constructor takes a byte array that's interpreted as a [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) integer, and you can then use the `add` function to add the two. Keep in mind that `add` doesn't modify either of the objects, as BigIntegers are immutable. Instead, it returns a new object.

Comment: Could you provide an example of putting my strings into this byte[]?